# What are .chk files among .so libraries purpose

Tags: shared-library

I'm preparing a chrooted environment for some command. I'm using CentOS 6. To determine what libraries do I need in my enviroment, I'm using `strace`:

```
strace <command> | grep open > needed.files.log
```

In the resulting log I see following lines:

```
open("/usr/lib64/libfreeblpriv3.chk", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/usr/lib64/libfreeblpriv3.so", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/usr/lib64/libsoftokn3.chk", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/usr/lib64/libsoftokn3.so", O_RDONLY) = 5
```

I'm curious what are these `.chk` files for? Do I need to copy them to my chrooted environment with the `.so` libraries? I didn't find any information about them with google, it only shows me information about DOS/Windows `chkdsk`.

Answer (score 1):

Checksum files required for the NSS softoken to operate in FIPS 140 mode - https://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tech-notes/tn6

If yes, than you shall need those.